# How can I block ALL installed windows software to access the internet, except for the browser?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, firewall, privacy

As you know, all big enterprises like google, Microsoft, Facebook and many others are collecting personal sensible data from people. They say that these data are for "enhancing experience", or to sell it to e-commerce, but they are liers. Indeed, they are collecting our information to track us.

There are a lot of tips on the internet on how to improve your privacy, like using a web browser other than the Google chrome family. For example, using Firefox with some good ublock, untrack extensions or using Tor browser. But as you might know, Microsoft Windows 10 has a built in mechanism which, even if you block telemetry, keeps sending hundreds of pieces of information to Microsoft in a single day (Research the web for that). So, perhaps we should use a more secure OS, like Linux, and while using the internet for browsing, block ALL firewall attempts from other software to contact the web. Is that really possible? I mean, can we block all other software except for browsing and would the OS still work fine without crashing?

Comment: You can use Windows Defender with Advanced Security to create a new firewall rule to block all programs in outbound rules. Then add exceptions for programs that you trust.

Comment: You don't need Defender to set Firewall Rules. BTW, there are scripts to block Windows data collection and advertising, e.g. https://winaero.com/blog/stop-windows-10-spying-on-you-using-just-windows-firewall/

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to do this. You're going to break internal Windows functions. **However,** if you really want to do this, follow these steps. For Windows 10:

1. Launch Windows Defender Firewall
2. Click "Advanced Settings" on the left
3. In the "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security" dialog that appears, click "Properties" in the right-hand "Actions" pane.
4. On all Profile tabs ("Domain Profile", "Private Profile", "Public Profile"), change the "Outbound connections" dropdown to "Block"
5. Click OK
6. Left-click "Outbound Rules" in the left-hand navigation tree
7. For each rule listed in the middle pane, click it once and then click "Disable Rule" in the right-hand "Actions" pane
8. Right-click "Outbound Rules" in the left-hand navigation tree. Click "New Rule" in the context menu that pops up.
9. Create a "Program" rule. Click Next
10. Click the "Browse" button and navigate to the browser's executable. Click Next
11. Select the "Allow the connection" radio button. Click Next
12. Select all Profile checkboxes to apply the rule to all profiles. Click Next
13. Give your rule a name, then click Finish.

This will give you exactly what you asked for, but it **will not** work the way you think it will.

Also, you cannot block Windows telemetry through Windows Firewall, it will ignore those rules and attempt to connect anyway; that's something you'd want to do on your border firewall.

Comment: Nice answer. However I don't see why it shouldn't work. I've never had Windows 10 but on 7 and older this was never causing any issues. I've used comodo firewall back then to block everything except for a few apps I wanted to remain internet access. Can you elaborate more on the deficits and breaking functions?

Comment: It's step #7 that will break everything. DNS won't work. HTTPS won't work. IPV6 in total won't work. Ping won't work. Pretty much anything networking related won't work, but it'll accomplish what he's looking for. You could go for the middle ground and selectively disable the rules, but it doesn't meet the question's requirement. Plus, like I said in my original answer, you can't block Windows telemetry via Windows Firewall anyway.

Comment: But, would it work in Windows 7 ? As far as I know, win7 doesn´t have telemetry, or has it ?

Comment: @DihelsonMendonça I would give it a try as for me under windows 7 something similar to this did work. However I didn't use Windows firewall, I used comodo firewall.

Comment: @spittingglass How come DNS won't work? Is this related specifically to win10? AFAIK the router handles DNS queries. I don't see why SSL would break either. Which parts of windows that will end up getting blocked are responsible for that? Editing your answer would benefit everyone more than adding onto comments by the way.

Comment: I could run another computer running a Linux distro with 2 netword adapters to use as a server, VPN, and Firewall to filter connections, if it would of any utility in order to do that. I´ve heard that commercial VPS are not very secure, but we can install a small server and run our won VPN server. Of course they are different things, but on a second computer we could install a better firewall and a VPN server, just to hide IP address also.